# circelci and deploying to gh pages - how to prevent CI from being triggered when deploying

Tags: circleci-2.0

Im trying to deploy to gh-pages and have CI "build" job with cirecleci2.

My problem is - when deploying new commit generated at "gh-pages" branch(which starts the CI again)
I tried to prevent it by filtering "gh-pages" with "ignore":

```
 version: 2
   jobs:
     build:
       branches:
         ignore: gh-pages
```

but im still getting ci error "No tests" (which means that CI default process triggered)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Circleci is very particular about formatting, simply moving gh-pages to a new line and prepending with a flag might resolve your issue.

I would try:

```
 version: 2
 jobs:
   build:
     branches:
       ignore: 
         - gh-pages
```

Hope that works for you!